# How Do I Access Databases Uploaded in Heroku in my Rails 5 App and my Heroku Account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Rails 5 app that I have uploaded to Heroku. I have the lowest PostgreSQL plan (hobby-dev 10,000 rows). I followed the Import instructions on this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import).

When I attempt to run my app I get a `relation "xxxx" does not exist` error with a `500 Internal Server Error`. When I checked the data section for my app none of my databases appear. I tried again to execute the following command from my multiple AWS S3 database dumps. Every time I did a refresh command on the data page it looked like the counts were increasing but when everything was done none of my databases appeared. No errors appeared in my terminal or in the data section so I assumed the databases were not there.

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL
```

I received an email stating that I have about 80% of the allocated rows for my plan so they are somewhere. I've done `heroku restart` but still cannot access them. I don't know where to find/access the databases or where to go from here.

Output of `heroku run rails c`:

```
[xxxxxxxxxx (master)]$ heroku run rails c
Running rails c on ⬢ xxxxxxxx... up, run.4346 (Free)
Loading production environment (Rails 5.0.1)
irb(main):001:0>
```

Comment: what happens when you run `heroku run rails c`?

Comment: try loading your models....`User.first`. Can you?

Comment: I just updated my question with the output. It gets to my Rails app but the first thing it does is check a database login on model User. That is where the app crashes with the "relation 'user' does not exist". I have no problems running it on my local machine. It's just when it's uploaded to Heroku. Where can I see my databases in Heroku?

Comment: @AnnaS Please post your comment as an answer and I will check it. I will explain what happened on your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATABASE_URL represents the HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL of the database you wish to restore to.` 
Did you do this? => `You must specify a database configuration variable to restore the database.`

Comment: When I first uploaded my app it did the hobby-dev add-on for me. I could not find the color url so I used the data-store name. They got loaded but I could not access them. I deleted that add-on and created a new one using the Heroku CLI and got the color url name and uploaded the data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [migrate your database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#migrate-your-database) in heroku? It might be the issue.

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

Anytime you want to migrate/seed or use any rake command on heroku, you need to `heroku run` it.

Comment: Your question caused me to review my question. By mistake I deleted the fact that I have no migrations in my application. I had run the rake db:migrate command after my imports just in case it worked a little differently in Heroku.